# Yii2 How to pass a range to search model

Tags: php, model, yii2

I need to search a range for a field. How do I apply a between or greater than/less than statement to the search model.

Something similar to this. However those attributes aren't valid in the Search Model

```
$params['MlsSearch']['min_price'] = 10;
$params['MlsSearch']['max_price'] = 100;

$searchModel = new ModelSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search($params);
```

Answer (score 18):

**1) Define attributes in the model.**

```
class ModelSearch extends Model
{
     public $min_price;
     public $max_price;

    /*....*/
}
```

**2) Make attributes safe**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
         /*... */
         [['min_price', 'max_price', ], 'safe'],
    ]
}
```

**3) Modify Search Function**

```
public function search($params)
{
    /*... */
    $query->andFilterWhere(['>', 'price', $this->min_price]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['<', 'price', $this->max_price]);
    /*... */
}
```

Comment: Great ! very helpful

Answer (score 7):

You can also use BETWEEN construction:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'price', $this->min_price, $this->max_price]);
```